# Are partial fraction decompositions unique

Tags: polynomials, laplace-transform, partial-fractions

For a given rational function $f(x)=P(x)/Q(x)$ with degree of $Q(x)$ greater than degree of $P(x)$ are there more than one way to split it up into partial fractions?

I do realize that the denominators for the terms corresponding to roots of $Q(x)$ must be unique. But could different different sets of numerators result in the same function $f(x)$?

Comment: Yes. Check this out if you're interested in a formal proof: http://www.m-hikari.com/imf/imf-2012/29-32-2012/cookIMF29-32-2012.pdf. Are you looking for a more intuitive reasoning?

Comment: I was mostly looking just for yes/no, but an intuitive reasoning would be interesting.